# Custom ERB inside an SCSS file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, erb

I'm using fonts hosted on AWS S3 inside an SCSS file. So far that's worked with public S3 URLs but for security reasons, I need to remove all public URLs from client-side code. I was hoping to do something like

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Helvetica'), local('Helvetica'),
    url('<%= presigned_url("fonts/Helvetica.woff2") %>') format("woff2");
}
```

In this case, `presigned_url` would be a helper method that fetches the S3 object via the asset key (`fonts/Helvetica.woff2`), and returns a presigned URL that expires.

I've tried adding the `.erb` extension to my SCSS file but it doesn't seem to work. Is this possible? Or did I miss a step?

Comment: The SASS compiler doesn't pass your files through ERB. In fact unless your running the ancient and very depreachiated Ruby compiler it's written in C or Dart. The next problem with this idea is that assets should be compiled at deploy time and not per request. I would push back and question if the "for security" rationale here is reasonable.